# Can't open partition

Tags: 18.04

I can't open my C: partition, but when I want to install something, I have an option to install to C:, D: and x: (ubuntu). How can I open C: or D: on Nautilus again?

Comment: You don't have drive letters in Ubuntu (C: and the like). Please update your question with the exact commands you are trying to run, and their output.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to be a little more descriptive about your setup and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: When I want to install something (in my case GTA San Andreas), I have C: and D: partition shown in menu where it asks me where I want to install the game, but I can't find it in Nautilus...